# What is the different between hook_validate and hook_node_validate in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I just know hook_validate is invoked before hook_node_validate but how to use these functions in appropriate case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation for `hook_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7):

> This hook is invoked only on the module that defines the node's
>   content type

Where are implementations of [`hook_node_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) is invoked on any content type.